# Check, Quiet and VerificationTest with messages?

Tags: message-coding, testing-and-verification

I have a `VerificationTest` that is expected to generate some messages. It runs inside of code that uses `Check` to `Abort[]` on any messages generated in non-test code.

This construction does not work as intended, however: The Messages generated inside of `VerificationTest` seem to leak and trigger `Check` (even though `$MessageList` is empty?).

This code:

```
Check[Echo@VerificationTest[Message[a::b]; True, True, {a::b}]; Echo@$MessageList, $Failed]
```

makes the test succeed, but `Check` returns `$Failed`, while this code:

```
Check[Quiet@Echo@VerificationTest[Message[a::b]; True, True, {a::b}]; Echo@$MessageList, $Failed]
```

makes the test fail, because the effect of `Quiet` causes the message to go unregistered within `VerificationTest` (I think).

What can I do here?

Is there maybe even a bug with one of `Check`, `Quiet` and/or `VerificationTest`?

Comment: Maybe I'll write my own `VerificationTest` that behaves exactly as I want.

Comment: Why would one expect `Check` to ignore messages just because they were issued within a `VerificationTest` or why would one expect `VerificationTest` to detect messages suppressed by `Quiet`?

Comment: @ilian `VerificationTest` effectively uses something like `Quiet` to prevent messages generated inside from reaching the front-end. It is confusing that they still reach `Check`. `Check[VerificationTest[Message[a::b]], $Failed]` gives $Failed, `Check[Quiet[Message[a::b]], $Failed]` doesn't, although neither `VerificationTest[Message[a::b]]` nor `Quiet[Message[a::b]]` print any messages.

Comment: @ilian also, usually when `Check` fails, `$MessageList` is non-empty, but compare `{Check[Message[a::b], $Failed], $MessageList}` and `{Check[VerificationTest[Message[a::b]], $Failed], $MessageList}`

Comment: (1) `VerificationTest` does not use `Quiet`. Still, by design it neither displays messages generated during testing nor puts them on `$MessageList` (2) Nevertheless, the messages do fire and `Check` reacts appropriately. For a simplified example, try `Check[Block[{$Messages, $MessageList = {}}, 1/0]; {$MessageList, 
  NoMessagesFired}, {$MessageList, SomeMessagesFired}]` (3) If you wrapped a `Quiet` around `1/0` the message would not fire at all.